# Recentering text in cell in Latex Table after adding an image to the cell next to it

Tags: tables, alignment

I have created a 3x3 table in Latex, where the the two cells in the first row to the right are merged. It looks something like this:

[image]

However, when I import the image, the text to the right (first row, the two merged cells to the right) jumps down 4-5 lines making the spacing huge. The following code has been used:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\includegraphics[width=3.8cm]{logo}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{Something} \\ \\ \textbf{asdsad - random text}\\\textbf{{dasdasd - Random text}}\\ \\ asdasdf - random text \\ \\
\end{tabular}}  \\
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
{\scriptsize Approved}\\2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{\scriptsize 1}\\2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{\scriptsize 1}\\2\end{tabular}   \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} \\2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{\scriptsize 1}\\2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{\scriptsize 1}\\2\end{tabular}   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to realign the text to the top of the cell with only one empty line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % it also load graphicx
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |>{\scriptsize}l|*{2}{>{\scriptsize}X|} }
    \hline
\includegraphics[width=3.8cm, valign=c]{example-image-duck} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}c|}{\makecell{Something\\ \\
                                                asdsad - random text\\
                                                dasdasd - Random text\\ \\
                                                asdasdf - random text}}       \\
    \hline
\makecell[l]{1\\ 2} & \makecell[l]{1\\2 } & \makecell[l]{1\\2 }    \\
    \hline
\makecell[l]{1\\ 2} & \makecell[l]{1\\2 } & \makecell[l]{1\\2 }    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

Comment: Thanks mate! That work perfectly